# Mongodb database backup on windows

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, nosql

Ive got a problem concerning the mongodump function provided in mongodb. When the below code is run on mongodb shell it doesnt respond,

```
Mongodump --db database1 --out path:
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mongodump  --db students --collection grades
```

Here students is the name of the database and grades is the name of the collection.

Running this command will create a folder named dump in your current working directory. A folder with the name of your database will be created inside the dump folder within which you'll get a collection_name.bson file and collection_name.metadata.json file.

P.S. : Make sure you're running this command outside mongo shell.